# PIP is now broken because I ran out of space

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I tried to run this command and got the following error:

> $ pip install --upgrade pip
>
> Collecting pip
>     Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
>       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 1.1MB/s
>
> Installing collected packages: pip
>
> Found existing installation: pip 9.0.1
>
> Uninstalling pip-9.0.1:
>
> Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.1
>
> Rolling back uninstall of pip
>
> Exception:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
>       with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
>
> OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cache.py'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 790, in install
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 759, in rollback_uninstall
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 135, in rollback
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py", line 265, in renames
>
> File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
>       mkdir(name, mode)
>
> OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/caches/**pycache**'

Now when i run:
`$ pip -h`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/bin/pip", line 7, in 
>       from pip import main
>     File "/opt/virtualenvs/appname/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
>   ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'

Will anyone help me figure this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the installation is now in an inconsistent state, which is unfortunate, but is there a reason you can't just delete the whole virtualenv and reinstall it?

Comment: I guess I could but I didn't want to go through that as it's a staging server.

Comment: Isn't the point of a staging server that it's disposable and you can wipe it and reinstall things, since it's not production infrastructure?

Comment: Sure but I was just handed the server and don't know how it was all setup. I feel it may take more time to reinstall the venv, but I could be wrong. Don't know if i'd do more harm than good.

Comment: @Chris then practise running through the steps needed on an independent machine by yourself to gain confidence and ensure minimum disruption. Being afraid to break things is smart, but refusing to act because of it is suicide.

Comment: Virtualenv is designed to be easy to wipe and reinstall, in combination with `pip freeze` which creates a `requirements.txt` file. Depending on exactly how things are set up this might or might not be sufficient to recreate everything, but if you don't have documentation on how to set up a staging server from scratch, now is a great time to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free up some space and try to reinstall pip

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python3 get-pip.py
```